# how to validate Perl Modules Installed in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, perl

I have a list of Perl Modules which needs to be installed on a new server . List of Perl Modules is like this

```
perl-Expect
perl-JSON
perl-Net-OpenSSH
perl-Test-Most
perl-DBD-Mock
```

Earlier we were having Amazon Linux box on which we used rpm command to check if the module is installed or not. I tried using `dpkg -l` command on Ubuntu to validate the packages are installed but I am able to search for exact match .

Ubuntu server version :

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:        20.04
```

Is there a way we can search for exact match if the Perl Module is installed or not . This is first time I am using Ubuntu

Comment: You need to know how ubuntu rename the package shipping the `Perl` module. If you does not know the name you can try to use the module to find out if it is installed or not.
Eg: `perl -MExpect` on my `debian` return : `Can't locate Expect.pm in @INC ...`

Comment: @DanieleGrassini When I ran it is the command it is waiting for the output and never came back any response

Comment: Yes we need run command on the required modules to make sure all are installed on the box

Comment: Then it means that the modules are installed. try to add an `-e '' ` like : `perl -MJSON -e ''`

Comment: @DanieleGrassini yes from perl -MExpect -e '' is working

Comment: so i think that the modules is installed on the system. You can use the same approach to test the others. If the modules aren't installed then `Perl` will hang with the `Can't locate...`